# Is it possible to incorporate QuickBooks PHP DevKit into CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Specifically speaking, is it possible to use Consolibyte's Quickbooks PHP DevKit into an app using the CodeIgniter framework?  If so, where would I place it in my directory structure, and how would I access it?  I'm just doing some preliminary research into whether or not this could be used to integrate my app with Quickbooks Online.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to use Consolibyte's Quickbooks PHP DevKit into an app using the CodeIgniter framework?

Yes, of course!

> If so, where would I place it in my directory structure, and how would I access it?

Entirely up to you. Usually people put it in a `library/quickbooks/` directory or something. Then, just use `require_once 'path/to/library/quickbooks/QuickBooks.php';` like you would with any other PHP script.

> I'm just doing some preliminary research into whether or not this could be used to integrate my app with Quickbooks Online.

It can be used for that.

You'll need a controller that kicks off the OAuth process. So basically you'll use the code from here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php#L134

To show the connect button, and then put this code into a controller to kick off OAuth:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php

From there, you can use the other example code snippets to exchange data with QuickBooks.

If you have trouble, post your code so we can see what you're doing (feel free to use our support forums if you need more detailed help/discussion: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply, Keith.  I've been impressed with your tool so far, so thank you very much for creating it!  I'll look to the support forums if I need any help.

Comment: @jldavis76  We may try to put together a CodeIgniter specific example sometime soon we can distribute too. We have one for QuickBooks desktop, but haven't got one for QuickBooks Online yet.

Comment: Thanks again!  I posted over on the support forum under the same userID.  I just wanted to give you a heads up so that if you see it, you don't have to repeat all of this information over there.  Thanks!